# Server Internal Server Error when running from service

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, flask, server

I have a flask server running as a service from a server.service file. It worked great and then I upgraded the database to MySQL and when the service runs it displays "Internal Server Error", but when I run the code manually it works fine.

Here is my server.service script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Server
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/jon/server
ExecStart=/home/jon/server/env/bin/gunicorn -k gevent -b 0.0.0.0:5080 app:app
Restart=always

[Install]
RequiredBy = multi-user.target
```

When I navigate to the correct location in a terminal and run the following everything works fine:

```
/home/jon/server/env/bin/gunicorn -k gevent -b 0.0.0.0:5080 app:app
```

I've done a daemon-reload and rebooted multiple times. Here is my config.py for reference.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


#WTForms confiuration
CSRF_ENABLED = True
SECRET_KEY = 'you-will-never-guess'


#SQL Alchemy Database config
if os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') is None:
    print('USING SQLIte')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ('sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db') + '?check_same_thread=False')
else:
    print('Using MySQL')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    #SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    #SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ('mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost/20200830MYSQL')
    

SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = os.path.join(basedir, 'db_repository')
SQLALCHEMY_RECORD_QUERIES = True
WHOOSH_BASE = os.path.join(basedir, 'search.db')

# slow database query threshold (in seconds)
DATABASE_QUERY_TIMEOUT = 0.5

#File Upload Config
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['html', 'htm', 'xlsx'])

# administrator list
ADMINS = ['#you@12example.com']

# pagination
POSTS_PER_PAGE = 50
MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS = 50
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with getting mysql to boot when it comes up, but I'm not sure. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Internal Server Error" ([HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error)) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I found the issue by running the following command: journalctl -u service-name

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to linux and didn't know how to look at the service log files. Using the following command I tracedback the error to my database being configured incorrectly:

```
journalctl -u server.service
```